# Is this statement about conservative fields and parallel circuits correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, conservative-field

I am wondering if this statement about parallel circuits and conservative fields is true?:

> *The voltage drop over resistors in parallel is the same because the electric field is conservative, so the work done on a charge only depends on the start and end point. The field is conservative because the force it generates consists of the electrostatic force (Coloumb) and a magnetic force. We can show that the electrostatic force is conservative, and the magnetic force on moving charges is perpendicular to the velocity vector, so it does not do any work on the charge. So the only force that does work on the charge is the electrostatic force.*

Is this statement correct?

Comment: Yes, however I would personally change it to, "The field is Conservative because the magnetic field that is generated is time invariant "

Comment: @jensenpaull Thank you very much. You are then using Faradays law of induction? Does my argument hold even if we didn't know that the magnetic field was time invariant?(How do we know that it is time-invariant?)

Comment: If we have an alternating current, the magnetic field generated is time dependant and thus the field is non conservative, and hence your above reasoning is incorrect. However in this case the definition of potential doesn't make sense, and for applications for engineering the non Conservative component is 'ignored' and is artificially removed when assigning a traditional definition of 'potential difference', this is done when radiative effects are negligible and are not wanting to be considered. However in the sense of pure physics, the field is non Conservative, and the traditional definition

Comment: Doesn't make sense, since a potential function requires a Conservative field. (There is a scalar potential function even in this case however it does not carry the same definition as you are used to)

Comment: Yes I am talking about faradays law, in the case where $\nabla × \vec{E} =0$(absence of a changing magnetic field) it follows $$\vec{E} = -\nabla V$$ whose integral form is the definition you are familiar with; $$V =- \int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dr}$$. In the case there is a changing magnetic  field, the relation becomes $\vec{E} = -\nabla V -\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$ and thus the definition of potential you are familiar with, cannot be recovered.

Comment: @jensenpaull Thank you very much! But can you please explain why my argument fail(without using Faraday and time-variant magnetic fields) when we have an alternating current?

Comment: Because solving maxwells equations for an alternating  current yields a non Conservative field. Conservativeness of the electric field is purely dependant on the time dependancy of the magnetic field, alternating current causes changing magnetic fields as per amperes law

Comment: @jensenpaull Thank you, I have one last question; in your first post you said you would change it to "The field is Conservative because the magnetic field that is generated is time invariant ", how would you argue that it is time invariant?

Comment: I assumed that your post was talking about DC circuits, and thus the current density is time invariant ( Found using Ohms law) meaning when solving maxwells equations we are left with a time invariant B field.

Comment: @jensenpaull Thank you!, yes I meant DC circuits. But I have one question about what you just wrote. If we have the power source and one reistor I agree that Ohms law gives us a constant current. But what if we have many resistors, then to use Ohms law like we did we have to know that each voltage drop over each resistor is constant, how do we know that?